# AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'explain_query'

Tags: python

I seem to be receiving an error when I try to start the server or run 'makemigrations'.

Can anybody point out what might be wrong?

I am using Django 4.0.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 119, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 313, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 82, in applied_migrations
    return {
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 320, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1507, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1348, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\compiler.py", line 294, in as_sql
    if self.query.explain_query:
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'explain_query'
```

Answer (score 3):

I just hit this snag as well while attempting to upgrade to Django 4.  As it turns out, it appears that today django-mssql-backend==2.8.1 is not Django 4 compatible.

It looks like there is an open bug report and patch in place to fix this, though.

Bug Report:
https://github.com/ESSolutions/django-mssql-backend/issues/125

Commit / Pull Request:
https://github.com/ESSolutions/django-mssql-backend/pull/126

A requirements file tweak might look something like this:

```
# django-mssql-backend==2.8.1 has a bug that is incompatible with Django 4.0.5
# the below commit directly resolves the conflict and should be removed when mainstreamed
git+https://github.com/ESSolutions/django-mssql-backend.git@b23d305#egg=django-mssql-backend
```

There may be other incompatibilities that are discovered aside from the explain_query.

Comment: Can't make it work, pip complains: Running command git checkout -q b23d305
  error: pathspec 'b23d305' did not match any file(s) known to git
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × git checkout -q b23d305 did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Answer (score 2):

I got here searching for:

> AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'explain_query'

While trying to upgrade from django 3.2 to 4.1.2

So in actuality it looks like the answer is to replace?:

```
    if self.query.explain_query:
```

With:

```
    if self.query.explain_info:
```

see:

- https://github.com/django/django/blob/b7b28c7c189615543218e81319473888bc46d831/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py#L861 ( from main, as of the time of this answer )

Answer (score 0):

Re second answer: I solved it by installing django-pyodbc-azure

Please do not install django-pyodbc-azure as it has dependency Django 2.1.XXX
It will uninstall your Django 4.X.X. and replace by Django 2.1.0

I have resoled the issue by following the instruction on the first answer, which is: https://github.com/ESSolutions/django-mssql-backend/pull/126/files

Answer (score 0):

use mssql-django engine instead

https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34715291)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by installing  django-pyodbc-azure

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).